# How to handle Propel environment variables

Tags: php, variables, orm, configuration, propel

I am trying to setup some configuration for unit-testing my application.
Therefore I will need to setup different database connections.
I have tried to follow the documentation ([Environment Variables Doc](http://propelorm.org/documentation/10-configuration.html#special-parameters-environment-variables))
but I don't understand where to save the environment variables so they can be found when I have something like:

```
dsn: "mysql:host=%env%;dbname=%env%"
```

in the propel.yaml file.

Google does not provide any solutions, as well as searching here.

The Documentation says i have to write them in a file.. but where?

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Env vars

When using Linux you can set environment vars like this:

```
$ export DB_HOST="localhost" 
$ export DB_NAME="dbname"
...
```

Thus you can grab vars with PHP Like this:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump($_ENV["DB_NAME"]);'
```

Or:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(getenv["DB_NAME"]);'
```

In order to set env vars on Windows follow this link: 
[How to Create a Environmental Variable Windows 7](http://How%20to%20Create%20a%20Environmental%20Variable%20Windows%207)

## Propel

On propel, you must set the parameters like (propel.yaml file):

```
propel:
  database:
      connections:
          default:
              adapter: mysql
              classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\DebugPDO
              dsn: mysql:host=%env.DB_HOST%;dbname=%env.DB_NAME%
```

And here goes some helpful links:

- [Linux: Set Environment Variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)
- [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How to Create a Environmental Variable Windows 7](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500)